# how to use go private repository from nexus?

Tags: go, nexus

I have a private repository on nexus, which is where I created a private repository for my golang project

I've already run export GOPRIVATE or GOPROXY but it needs authentication, in the documents I'm looking for, there's no way, has anyone experienced this?

```
common-util/@v/list: 401 Unauthorized
```

Comment: you can  pass credentials to fetch from private repos -> https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-module-repo-auth

Answer (score 1):

At the time of implementation of the Go repository in Nexus Repository, the Go client does not have a means of authentication. This means Nexus Repository instances with anonymous disabled will not be able to reach the Go endpoints, rendering proxy useless.